# Dealing with co-dependent not null columns

Tags: normalization, null, dependencies

Say I have a table `entities` (subclassed by `people` and `organizations` tables), where each entry requires a `primary_email_id`. The `entities` table looks like this:

```
entities
========
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
full_name VARCHAR(255)
primary_email_id
primary_address_id
primary_tel_id
```

This `primary_email_id` is a foreign key to a table `contacts`, which is structured like this:

```
contacts
========
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
entity_id INT NOT NULL
type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL -- ex: "tel", "email", "address", "fax", etc.
```

and has a companion table `contact_attributes`:

```
contact_attributes
==================
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
contact_id INT NOT NULL
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL -- ex: "ext" or "username"
value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL -- ex: "+25" or "coolboss27"
```

I think it makes sense requiring that the `primary_email_id` be `NOT NULL` and that the `entity_id` in the `contacts` table be not null, but this co-dependence creates a problem. When creating an entity for the first time, we must have a `primary_email_id` to put in the row. But to do this, we must create a `contact` (and `contact_attribute` of `email: ...@...`). However to create that `contact`, we need to have already created the `entity` we're trying to create. So we are stuck.

I guess that means that I cannot have both the `entity_id` in `contacts` and the `primary_email_id` in `entities` be `NOT NULL`, and presumably `primary_email_id` is the one that should be nullable. This could be partially solved by including the actual `primary_email_address` instead of an `id`, but then the table is no longer normalized and I definitely don't want that.

Is there something I'm missing here or is making `primary_email_id` nullable just a necessary tradeoff?

Answer (score 1):

First, a name like 'entities' is too vague. The common name for org or individual is 'parties'.

Second, people can have zero, one, or many addresses, and can share the same address. It's a many2many relationship.

I would do it like this (using STI here, but break it out to CTI if you like):

```
PARTIES
id
type (org or individual)
name

ADDRESSES
id
type
address_info...

PARTY_ADDRESSES
party_id
address_id
role (ex 'sales', 'service', 'mobile', 'work', ...)
priority
```

Your validation rule would be that a party must have an address of type 'email' whose priority is higher than any other of their addresses. Business rules are best enforced via <strike>triggers</strike> any applicable logic and not your data model.

Comment: Generally you want to avoid using triggers to enforce business rules if you can at all help it.  Use constraints if possible.  Foreign keys, check constraints etc.  Triggers tend to be slow and are really easy to mess up.

Comment: @Kenneth_fisher, foreign keys are part of the data model. Check constraints are great if you got em and if single table. Triggers necessary for multi table biz rules. My main point was that data model should be generalized and biz rules should not compromise a good data model.

Comment: I can certainly agree with that.  If you try to build your business rules to tightly into the data model then when your business rules change (which they almost always do) then you're messed over.

Comment: "Second, people can have zero, one, or many addresses, and can share the same address. It's a many2many relationship." I agree that someone can have multiple addresses, but I don't believe in tying the same address record to multiple people, because if one person moves, you will probably accidentally move both people's records. Your advice about the name "entities" is well taken.